# Transition and center the card in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am building a page in react to show price. So I have create a Card element to put all the data inside and then re-use it.

For now, it looks like this:\

[image]

Please do not pay attention to the red background, I am just using it to easily see UI placement.

I am trying to get this :

[image]

To do so, I have created a class `PriceCard` as below:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import TextContents from '../../assets/translations/TextContents';

import './PriceCard.css';

class PriceCard extends React.Component {  

    render() {



        let savingMessage;
        if(this.props.buttontext === TextContents.BuyCreditsBtn){
            savingMessage = <h6>{TextContents.SubscribeAndSave} {this.props.percent}{TextContents.Percent}</h6>
        }

        return(
            <div className="price-card-container">
                <h4>{this.props.price}</h4>
                <h5>{this.props.credits} {TextContents.Credits}</h5>
                <p> {this.props.desc} </p>
                <div>
                <Button bsPrefix="price-card-blue-button">
                        {this.props.buttontext}
                </Button>
                </div>
                {savingMessage}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PriceCard;
```

and css is :

```
.price-card-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 420px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    border-radius: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

.price-card-container:hover {
    width: 330px;
    height: 462px;
    background-color: #14cff0;
    transition: linear;
}

.price-card-container h4 {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 0.8;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #14cff0;
}

.price-card-container:hover h4{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.price-card-container h5 {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 0.8;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: left;
    color: #333333;
}

.price-card-container:hover h7{
    color: #09778b;
}

.price-card-container h6 {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #14cff0;
}

.price-card-container:hover h6{
    color: #ffffff;
}

.price-card-container p {
  font-family: Source Sans Pro;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  line-height: 1.68;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-align: left;
  color: #616161;
}

.price-card-container:hover p{
    color: white;

}

.price-card-container:hover .price-card-blue-button {
    border-radius: 21px;
    border-style: solid; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #14cff0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    border-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}

.price-card-blue-button {
    border-radius: 21px;
    border-style: solid; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ffffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: #14cff0; 
    border-color: #14cff0;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}


.price-card-blue-button:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
}

.price-card-blue-button:active {
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    transform: translateY(4px);
}

.price-card-container:hover .price-card-blue-button {
    border-radius: 21px;
    border-style: solid; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #14cff0;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 18px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.14);
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: #ffffff; 
    border-color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
}
```

Then I include it in my page has done below in:

```
import React from 'react';
import PriceCard from '../components/materialdesign/PriceCard';
import { Col, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import PriceInfo from '../config/PriceInfo';
import TextContents from '../assets/translations/TextContents';
import './HowItWorks.css';

class HowItWorks extends React.Component {
    
    render() {

        const CreditBundles = 
                <div className="hiw-price-info-container">
                    <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw1} price={PriceInfo.Credits1.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Credits1.values.credits} percent={PriceInfo.Credits1.values.percentage} buttontext={TextContents.BuyCreditsBtn}/>
                    <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw2} price={PriceInfo.Credits2.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Credits2.values.credits} percent={PriceInfo.Credits2.values.percentage} buttontext={TextContents.BuyCreditsBtn}/>
                    <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw2} price={PriceInfo.Credits3.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Credits3.values.credits} percent={PriceInfo.Credits3.values.percentage} buttontext={TextContents.BuyCreditsBtn}/>
                
                </div>

        const Subscription =                 
                <div>
                <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw1} price={PriceInfo.Subscription1.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Subscription1.values.credits} buttontext={TextContents.SubscribeBtn}/>
                <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw1}price={PriceInfo.Subscription2.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Subscription2.values.credits} buttontext={TextContents.SubscribeBtn}/>
                <PriceCard desc={TextContents.TextDescHiw1} price={PriceInfo.Subscription3.values.price} credits={PriceInfo.Subscription3.values.credits} buttontext={TextContents.SubscribeBtn}/>
                </div>

        return (
            <div className="hiw-container">
                <h1> {TextContents.HowItWorksTitle} </h1>
                <p> {TextContents.VillagePassport} </p>
                {CreditBundles}
            </div>
        );
    }
    
}

export default HowItWorks;
```

and the css

```
.hiw-container {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom:5rem;
    width: 70%;
}

.hiw-container h1{
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;  
}

.hiw-container h2{
    font-family: Fredoka One;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 0.58;
    letter-spacing: -0.8px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #333333;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-top: 5rem;
}

.hiw-container p{
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 1.6;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    text-align: center;
    color: #616161;
}

.hiw-price-info-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: red;
}

/* tablet, ipad  version (change font-size here if needed)*/
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){

    .hiw-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom:5rem;
        width: 50%;
    }

}

/* mobile version (change font-size here if needed)*/
@media (max-width: 600px) {

    .hiw-container {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom:5rem;
        width: 70%;
    }

}
```

I am trying to understand how to set a fix space between each card, make sure they are center in the screen and have smooth or linear transition when going hover a tile.

the mecamism to "transform" the style of the tile when going hover is done and works, I just have an issue on the general placement.

Any idea how to make it looks like the design ? it would be great to also have tranition between defaukt and hove to make the change looking like's it's ther

Comment: You can use `display: flex` on `price-card-container` to place items inside it accordingly. Go and research for how to use flex. As a suggestion, take a look at this website- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

If you want some space between your cards don't set the margin-left and right to auto but to a specific value.

```
.hiw-container {
    margin-left: 0.5rem;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;

    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-bottom:5rem;
    width: 70%;
}
```

To make this look cleaner do the following:

```
.hiw-container {
    margin: 5rem 0.5rem;
    width: 70%;
}
```

For the general placement add a container or div around all of your cards. Give this container a certain width that contains all of your cards and set the margin-left and right to auto.